# did an upgrade on KIWI I am using DOCKER container to run with now my manage.py fails for django asserts

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I did an upgrade per the documentation at
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html

Upgrading
Steps to Reproduce

cd Kiwi/
git pull # to refresh docker-compose.yml
docker-compose down
make docker-image if you build from source or

docker pull kiwitcms/kiwi # to fetch latest version from Docker Hub
docker pull centos/mariadb # to fetch the latest version for MariaDB
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
Actual results

When I run docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate I get an assert of:

```
sudo docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/init.py", line 84, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in init
super(Connection, self).init(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
self.check()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in _run_checks
issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
return self._cursor()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in exit
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/init.py", line 84, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in init
super(Connection, self).init(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")
Expected results

There is no assert and I can get into my web server currently I get only a 500 error even running it on local.
Additional info (Python traceback, logs, etc.)
@powaycraig60
Author
powaycraig60 commented 17 hours ago

getting this when not doing a -d on the up command

Creating kiwi_db ... done
Creating kiwi_web ...
Creating kiwi_web ... done
Attaching to kiwi_db, kiwi_web
db_1 | => sourcing 20-validate-variables.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 25-validate-replication-variables.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 30-base-config.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Processing basic MySQL configuration files ...
db_1 | => sourcing 60-replication-config.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 70-s2i-config.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Processing additional arbitrary MySQL configuration provided by s2i ...
db_1 | => sourcing 40-paas.cnf ...
db_1 | => sourcing 50-my-tuning.cnf ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Starting MySQL server with disabled networking ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Waiting for MySQL to start ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.13-MariaDB) starting as process 27 ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 32M, instances = 1, chunk size = 32M
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=4674060
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 16 pages from redo log.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.13 started; log sequence number 4710191; transaction id 11017
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/data/ib_buffer_pool
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/data/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@825ca2ceb711' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALU
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 6 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1 | Version: '10.3.13-MariaDB' socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' port: 0 MariaDB Server
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 8 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 MySQL started successfully
db_1 | => sourcing 40-datadir-action.sh ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 Running datadir action: upgrade-warn
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 MySQL server version check passed, both server and data directory are version 10.3.
db_1 | => sourcing 50-passwd-change.sh ...
web_1 | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.21.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.945703 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH01909: 172.21.0.3:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.950629 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH01909: 172.21.0.3:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 Setting passwords ...
web_1 | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.21.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.978504 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH01909: 172.21.0.3:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.979275 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH01909: 172.21.0.3:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.979669 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 9 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db_1 | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.997193 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1c mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
web_1 | [Mon Feb 10 22:31:18.997481 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8:tid 140513779747072] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
kiwi_db exited with code 1
db_1 | => sourcing 20-validate-variables.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 25-validate-replication-variables.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 30-base-config.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Processing basic MySQL configuration files ...
db_1 | => sourcing 60-replication-config.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 70-s2i-config.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Processing additional arbitrary MySQL configuration provided by s2i ...
db_1 | => sourcing 40-paas.cnf ...
db_1 | => sourcing 50-my-tuning.cnf ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Starting MySQL server with disabled networking ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:17 Waiting for MySQL to start ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.13-MariaDB) starting as process 27 ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 32M, instances = 1, chunk size = 32M
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=4674060
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 16 pages from redo log.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.13 started; log sequence number 4710191; transaction id 11017
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/data/ib_buffer_pool
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/data/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@825ca2ceb711' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALU
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 6 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1 | Version: '10.3.13-MariaDB' socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' port: 0 MariaDB Server
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 8 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 MySQL started successfully
db_1 | => sourcing 40-datadir-action.sh ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 Running datadir action: upgrade-warn
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 MySQL server version check passed, both server and data directory are version 10.3.
db_1 | => sourcing 50-passwd-change.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:18 Setting passwords ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:18 9 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db_1 | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db_1 | => sourcing 20-validate-variables.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 25-validate-replication-variables.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 30-base-config.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:20 Processing basic MySQL configuration files ...
db_1 | => sourcing 60-replication-config.sh ...
db_1 | => sourcing 70-s2i-config.sh ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:20 Processing additional arbitrary MySQL configuration provided by s2i ...
db_1 | => sourcing 40-paas.cnf ...
db_1 | => sourcing 50-my-tuning.cnf ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:20 Starting MySQL server with disabled networking ...
db_1 | ---> 22:31:20 Waiting for MySQL to start ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'ignore-db-dir' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'ignore_db_dirs' instead.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.13-MariaDB) starting as process 27 ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 32M, instances = 1, chunk size = 32M
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=4674060
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 16 pages from redo log.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.13 started; log sequence number 4710200; transaction id 11017
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/data/ib_buffer_pool
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/data/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@825ca2ceb711' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALU
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 6 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1 | 2020-02-10 22:31:20 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mariadb103/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Comment: I see some hints in your log. `please run mysql_upgrade to create it`. What versions were you upgrading from and which are you on now? You might have to check the changelogs of your installed packages. Could also just be that your SQL server did not start up. You might want to try searching for a few of those individual errors.

Comment: I am not sure what I got last time but I have version 7.3 that I am trying to run currently. The docker looks like it has several versions loaded on it even from running their upgrade process on their website.

Comment: apt-cache madison docker-ce
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages

Comment: Okay I am unsure how to get the mysql upgrade to work correctly as it seems it was not installed. which is odd since it was working. I am using docker so I am not sure why mysql is not there. Did I need a vert env for docker to work with Kiwi? worst case I will simply remove everything and start from scratch I suppose. I will loose allot of work...

Comment: Yea, it might be best to start from scratch. Going to be hard to get good help with this type of problem from Stack Overflow. Keep your current work around, and hopefully it will be easy to copy it over or use it as reference. You might find out what the problem was along the way. Good luck!